# how to pull all commits of a branch contains commits that mentioned the issues and not merged yet?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have last 10 commit at my workplace that each of them mentioned an issue that I made myself,

for example :

`git commit -m "last commit close #10"`

I pushed all commit at my office,
now in my home I want to `git pull origin mybranch` and get these last 10 commits, But since I am the maintainer and not the owner of repository and also have no permission to merge, I can't merge these issues. and after `git pull origin mybranch` these last 10 commit not pull to the home local. only the commits that is before the issue mentioned will pulling and say : `Already up to date.`

is there a way to pull all these last commits?

Comment: "Already up to date" means you already have all the commits from `mybranch`. Check your history: `git log --oneline --graph HEAD origin/mybranch`. If you don't see your commits there, check `git log --oneline --graph --all`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try fetching the changes?

```
git fetch origin mybranch
```

Comment: yes, I tried , not work